# Angular 5: Unit testing getters and setters

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am unable to test getter and setter functions in Angular 5 using Karma. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

The value is set and then the test waits a short duration for the setter function to resolve before calling the getter function. Here is the code:

**service.ts**

```
set header(h: string) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this._header = h;
    });
}

get header(): string {
    return this._header;
}
```

**test.ts**

```
before(() => {
    service = new Service()
});

it('updates header', (done) => {
    const header = 'test header';
    service.header = header;

    // Give header time to update
    return Promise.delay(200)
    .then(() => {
         expect(service.header).to.equal(header);
    })
});
```

I would expect the assertion to resolve successfully however I get an error

> AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'test header'

Comment: Did you find any solution on how to properly unit test setters/getters in angular?

Comment: Maybe that way ?
```const spy = spyOnProperty(service, 'header', 'get').andReturn('test header');
expect(service.header).toBe('test header');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();```

Comment: Try adding `this.cd.detectChanges()` after assigining `service.header = header`. Where `cd` is an instance of `ChangeDetectionRef`

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason that you wrap your set content into a zone ?

For 99% of all async activities i love the "fakeAsync" and the "tick" method of Angular.

```
it('should update header', fakeAsync( ()=>{
  const header = 'test header';
  service.header = header;
  tick() // <= Will wait for for all microtransactions to finish
  expect(service.header).to.equal(header);
}))
```

There are quite a few good articles about Macro- and Microtransactions in JavaScript.
The short version is, that Promises and Subscriptions of an observable-emit are microtransactions.

"setTimeout" is an example for a macrotransaction.

The best about "tick()" in a fakeAsync-UnitTest is, that you dont have to make sugestions how long the code will need to wait. "tick()" just drains the microtransaction-queue so all waiting micro transactions will be resolved, before the test proceeds.

You can use them also when waiting for the changeDetection of Angular-components. :-)

I hope that helps a bit.

warm regards